# Possible reasons why this javascript is not running when call it using ajax/jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

please take a look of this, the file [demo.php](http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/5pGs36l4Y7) is an example of the google chart framework. If you open it directly it works just fine.

Then, i need to embed the contend render by demo into another page using an ajax call with jquery simple like [this](http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/YsBxjw8UZ7). As you will see, it will not work, the script makes the ajax call but the javascript code in demo.php seems to be not executed. How can i solve this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console/Firebug?

Comment: Links to code elsewhere may be a helpful *adjunct* to a question, but always include the relevant code *in the question itself*. People shouldn't have to click through to random places to help you, and moreover Stack Overflow is meant to be a resource not only for you now, but for others with similar issues in the future. The content of external sites can change, disappear, move, etc., which would render this question completely useless to anyone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try wrapping the whole google chart code within a `setTimeout`

```
function drawChart() {
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
  // .....
  chart.draw(data, options);
}

setTimeout(drawChart, 200);
```

Comment: same problem, no data rendered